# How can I get the folder ID of a folder in my drive using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

For a project I am working on I created a trigger to run my makeCopy() function at the beginning of every year. The goal is to make a copy of a spreadsheet and save it in a folder already created in my drive. In this function I also create a new folder for the new year.

```
function makeCopy(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var d = new Date();
  var year = d.getYear();
  var FolderName = "Time Off Request - " + year;

  DriveApp.createFolder(FolderName);

  year = year - 1;
  var FileName = "Copy of Time Off Request - " + year; 
  Logger.log(FolderName);
  FolderName = "Time Off Request - " + year;
  var FolderID = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(FolderName).next().getId();
  Logger.log(FolderID);

  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderID);
  Logger.log(destFolder);


  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(FileName, destFolder);

}
```

This code actually ran and worked the first time. However, every time I try to test it again I get the error, "Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. " On the line where I try to get my folder ID. How can I fix this error and get the folder ID of the folder in my drive so I can make a copy of the spreadsheet to that folder.

Comment: You are logging the folder name before defining it... The name is probably not correct otherwise your code should run without error. You could use a try/catch structure to prevent the error stopping execution.

Comment: I define the folder name at the top of the script before I log it. I then re define it so that the year changes because the folder being created has the same name except it is one year ahead that's the only difference.

Comment: Yeah I found the mistake Serge! The folder name was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that specific error, `Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.`, because the search for that folder name yielded an empty result set.
If you alter your program structure to only use `next()` if the iterator's `hasNext()` method returns true, you will not get that error anymore. However, such a change will not make your search term suddenly find results. It does, however, allow for making repeated attempts with different search queries.

I suggest renaming your variables to be expressive of their intent:

```
// Copy the current file into last year's folder, and create this year's folder.
function makeCopy() {
  var now = new Date();
  var thisYear = now.getYear();
  var lastYear = thisYear - 1;

  var query = "Time Off Request - " + lastYear;
  var folderIterator = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(query);
  // Instead of throwing an error, you could modify this to be a while loop
  // that requests a search term from the user - see Browser/UI and inputBox
  // and updates folderIterator. If you do that, you'll want to add guards
  // that ensure the correct folder will be the first result.
  if (!folderIterator.hasNext()) {
    throw new Error("Bad search term - no folders with name '" + query + "' exist!");
  }

  var lastYearFolder = folderIterator.next();
  console.log({message: "Backup of Time Off Requests",
               query: query,
               destFolder: lastYearFolder.getName()}
  ); // View->Stackdriver Logging

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var backupName = "Copy of Time Off Request - " + lastYear; 
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(backupName, lastYearFolder);

  // Before exiting, now that the backup is done, create this year's folder.
  DriveApp.createFolder("Time Off Request - " + thisYear);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[createFolder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfoldername) returns a Folder object, but the code didn't take advange of this. Instead of

```
DriveApp.createFolder(FolderName);
```

Use

```
var myFolder =  DriveApp.createFolder(FolderName);
```

Then to get the folder id use [getId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getid)

```
var FolderID = myFolder.getId();
```